# How i can send null values in protobuf 3 using java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc-java

I know we can't send null values using protobuf 3.

but i can see people are using **oneof** to achieve this.

```
message GetHomePageDataRequest{
  string client_id = 1;
  string user_id = 2;
  oneof one_of_importance {
    google.protobuf.NullValue null_importance = 3;
    string importance = 4;
  }
}
```

but i am not sure about server/client look like for above request. how we can write code so we get to know that importance is null or not?

i am using gRpc with protobuf 3 using java8

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the `oneof` API exposes an enum, per `oneof`, that tells you which option is selected; see [docs here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#oneof). Interestingly, you don't actually need a specific value for the null option - it is sufficient simply not to assign a value at all, and test for the `*_NOT_SET` enum.

Note that there is also now *experimental* support for presence tracking in proto3, which works the same as `optional` did in proto2; essentially, if you use `--experimental_allow_proto3_optional` with `protoc`, you can then use:

```proto
message GetHomePageDataRequest{
  string client_id = 1;
  string user_id = 2;
  optional string importance = 4; // or 3, if you can still change it
}
```

and all of the usual APIs to test for a value and clear a value etc will be generated, meaning: you will be able to distinguish *explicit* empty values from missing values. The proto3 presence APIs are discussed [more here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/v3.12.0/docs/field_presence.md).

Comment: --experimental_allow_proto3_optional this is something we need to add in .proto file

or it will be some gradle task?

Comment: that is a parameter to the command-line executable itself - not part of the schema file; I don't know how you are executing protoc - if that is via gradle, then yes: it would need to go via that